# How do I change the Created By for my crossrider plugin?

Tags: crossrider

When users install my browser it shows the plugin created by the name listed under my crossrider dev account.  I'd like to change that to my company name but the site won't let me change the name.  How can I change it to show my company name vs my first and last name?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email support@crossrider.com from the email address currently associated with the account. In the email, provide:

- Current Account Name: the name currently associated with the account
- Extension ID(s): One or more IDs of extensions in the account
- New Account Name: the desired name for the account

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]